# Python - import Image as PIL_Image ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

Tags: python

I am running into the below error.
I have pip installed both Pil and Pillow and still receiving the error

```
import Image as PIL_Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

Not sure what I'm missing here

Comment: Have you tried aliasing `Image` like this: `from PIL import Image as PIL_Image`?

Comment: @AlessandroTogni Tried there, still no luck. I don't think importing Image is necessary as I don't call it in the script? The script works with PowerPoint

Comment: That's a different problem and i cannot help you without having a look at the script and the data.

Comment: @AlessandroTogni the script is large and is sensitive to the organization, The script essentially reads in a PowerPoint template using
**prs = Presentation(pptx=r'C:\Users\cob\OneDrive - abc\Desktop\Files\E2E Gantt\template_4_python.pptx')** and then outputs a PowerPoint with dots marking important dates for each product. There is a product per slide

Comment: I'm sorry, i cannot guess the script logic.

Comment: @AlessandroTogni unfortunately the code is too large I tried pasting it in

Answer (score 1):

install your module

```
pip install Pillow
```

and try to import in this way

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution , Pillow is installed and I also currently have from PIL import Image in my code but still no luck. The code itself outputs a powerpoint so I don't think from PIL import Image is required? , I know the python-pptx package works with Pillow and Pillow works with Image (all are installed) I'm just not sure why it isn't working